# почему при множественном delete указателя-члена класса все валится?

Tags: c++, память

здравствуйте, задумался над следующим вопросом, а именно, почему валится прога:

```
struct hero {
    hero()
    :ptr(new int[5]{1,2,2,2,1})
    {
    }
    hero(const hero& rhs) {
        ptr = new int[5];
        memcpy(ptr, rhs.ptr, 5 * sizeof(int));
    } 
    ~hero() _NOEXCEPT {
    //  delete[] ptr;
    }

    int* ptr;
};


int main() {

    hero a;
    delete[] a.ptr;
    delete[] a.ptr; //крашится

    int* ptr = nullptr;
    delete[] ptr;
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

в чем разница принципиальная при `delete[]` обычного указателя?

ОТВЕТ:
всем спасибо за ответы... мне надо было б просто написать так

```
int* ptr = new int[3];
delete[] ptr;
delete[] ptr;
```

и так же был бы крах и не было бы вообще этого вопроса... а я прост подумал, что есть какая-то разница при delete указателя-члена класса и обычного

Comment: а вы зачем два раза delete[] вызываете?
А правило такое: если new[] то и delete[]

Comment: специально валю приложение и хочу понять почему оно валится от этого...

Comment: Диспетчер памяти считает, что там - распределенный блок, лезет и пытается трактовать служебную информацию освобожденного блока как распределенного, и... думаю, понятно?

Comment: вот тут все хорошо расписано и доступно, что именно происходит при удалении и почему нельзя удалять два раза подряд https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: @Harry, не шарю в низкоуровневых вещах... максимум только читал про страницы памяти

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нельзя дважды вызывать delete (и delete[]) для не нулевого указателя. Сам delete  не зануляет указатель, а попытка повторно удалить уже удаленный объект почти всегда приводит к падению.

В этом куске

```
int* ptr = nullptr;
delete[] ptr;
delete[] ptr;
```

Вы пытаетесь удалить нулевой указатель. А с ним так можно.

Вот этот кусок

```
delete[] a.ptr;
delete[] a.ptr; //крашится
```

можно переписать так

```
delete[] a.ptr;
a.ptr = nullptr;
delete[] a.ptr; // уже не будет
a.ptr = nullptr;
```

и все будет ок.

А можно просто начать использовать умные указатели и забыть о подобных проблемах.

Answer (score 5):

Ваша проблема в **повторном** удалении.
Оператор `delete` (как и `delete[]`), *не меняет значения переданного указателя*. Так что после освобождения памяти вы вновь пытаетесь освободить ее. Что категорически не рекомендуется, ибо чревато undefined behaviour.

Если вы хотите показать нижними строками, что вот, если использовать не `new[]`, то все хорошо - то нет, вы не правы. Тут все хорошо просто потому, что для нулевого указателя оператор `delete` не делает *ничего*.

Что касается применения `delete[]` и `delete` к "обычному указателю", то вы получите те же неприятности, если этот указатель *не будет предварительно создан с помощью* `new[]` или `new`. Т.е. при

```
int i = 0;
int * p = &x;
delete[] p;
```

вы опять нарываетесь на неприятности... :)

При этом заметим, что следует использовать оператор удаления, соответствующий оператору выделения памяти: `new` - `delete`, `new[]` - `delete[]` (да, на практике для простых фундаментальных типов наподобие `int` или `char` вы, скорее всего, неприятностей не получите, но для чего-то более серьезного - запросто).